# Getting text from range in google sheets to a google doc NOT in a table

Tags: google-sheets, copy, doc

I have read everything I could find on this site and others about methods of getting text out of a google sheet and into a google doc.  I don't want the "data" in a table. It's not a huge amount of data to work with, so I'm able to tinker with the source sheet a bit and found a solution using a ListItem append approach.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
    function onOpen() {
      const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Agenda')
      .addItem('CreateAgenda', 'createagenda')
      .addToUi();
    }

    function createagenda() {
        // take info from agenda topic google spreadsheet and put in a google doc

    var documentId=DriveApp.getFileById('_______________').makeCopy().getId();
    //add today's date to new filename
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var theDate = curr_month + "_" + curr_date + "_" + curr_year;

    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(theDate + '_CommitteeAgenda');

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AgendaPlanning");

    //Determine how many items are in the list to set count in For Loop
    sheet.getRange('B2').activate(); // Starting cell in column with agenda items
    sheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
    var last_row_submissions = sheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex();

    const body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();

    for (var i=2; i<= last_row_submissions; i++){
    var currentline = sheet.getRange(i,14).getValue();
    var agenda_item = body.appendListItem(currentline);
  }
    var documentsInPacket = sheet.getRange("B28").getValue();
    var doclist = body.appendListItem(documentsInPacket);
  }
```

For the  most part this works because items on the agenda document are numbered, but because I've used the ListItem approach, the final item (Documents) has a number to it (18) which I don't want.  Since someone has to go in and put in meeting info (zoom link, etc.) then having one more thing to do isn't horrible, but....

15. Minutes (6:30)
16. Commentary  (6:35)
17. Adjourn (6:40)
18. Documents:  Superintendent report; .....etc.

? Is there an easier way to do this? Can I get rid of the number preceding the last item?  How can you get the value of a cell from sheets and have google doc accept it as text?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `body.appendParagraph(documentsInPacket)` instead of      `body.appendListItem(documentsInPacket)` to achieve the results you are looking for.